# Distribution of bounded summation of i.i.d random variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

We have a set of positive random variables $\boldsymbol X=\{X_1, X_2,\ldots\}$, where $X_1, X_2,\ldots$, are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.). The CDF $F(x)$ and PDF $f(x)$ for $X_i$ are known in advance.

Define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.

As we can see $\boldsymbol X$ can be viewed as inter-arrival times for a renewal process, and $S_n$ denotes each arrival epoch.

Next we define a variable $K$: $K=\inf\, \{n\mid S_n>T\}$ (or $K=\min\, \{n\mid S_n > T\}$), where  $T$ is a constant.

Then

1. what is the distribution of $K$?
2. what is the distribution of $S_K$?

I already know that the PDF for $S_n$, denoted by $f_n$, can be computed by $f_n=f^{*n}=f*f*\cdots *f$, the $n$-fold convolution power of $f(x)$. By Laplace Transform, we can convert the convolution to multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF of $K$ is 
$$ P(K \le n) = P(S_n > T) = \int_{T}^\infty dt\; f_n(t)$$
The CDF of $S_K$ (for $s > T$) is
$$\eqalign{P(S_K \le s) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(K = n, S_n \le s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(S_{n-1} \le T, T < S_n \le s)\cr &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^T dt\;  f_{n-1}(t) \int_T^s dr\; f(r-t)}$$

EDIT: the $n=1$ term needs to be modified since $S_0 = 0$ doesn't have a density.
So (assuming of course $T > 0$) it's 
$$P(S_K \le s) = \int_T^s dr\; f(r) + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_0^T dt\;  f_{n-1}(t) \int_T^s dr\; f(r-t)$$

Comment: The CDF of $K$ is straightforward to understand, but since $f_n(t)$ involves convolution, 1) is there any way to reduce the computational complexity for computers? 2) the values of $K$ are actually discrete, should this be considered while deriving the CDF for $S_K$? 3) why $f(r-t)$ rather than $f_n(r)$ is at the end of $P(S_k\leq s)$?

Comment: 1) memoization.
2) Thats why it's a sum over $n$ rather than an integral.
3) Because $S_n = S_{n-1} + X_n$.

Comment: Thanks! It's clear that I can compute the expectation of $K$ $E[K]$ according to its CDF. But this still involves convolution. Is there any simpler way to derive $E[K]$? Is $E[K]=\lceil {T/E[X]} \rceil$ correct?

Comment: No, but in the limit as $T \to \infty$ you have the Elementary Renewal Theorem.

Comment: $T$ will not has a limit in my case. Why $E[K]=\lceil {T/E[X]} \rceil$ is incorrect? This seems straightforward based on the definition of $K$.

Comment: For one thing, there's no reason for $E[K]$ to be an integer.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My thoughts on this was too naive. Let $N(t)$ denote the counting process, it's easy to see that $N(Z)=K-1$, so $E[N(Z)]=E[K]-1$. Define $m(t)=E[N(t)]$, $m(t)$ is the renewal function, and it can be solved by the renewal equation using Laplace transform, so $m(Z)$ can be computed. In this way, $E[K]$ can be derived by $E[K]=m(Z)+1$. Is this correct?

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you again, but I cannot figure out how to compute $\int_0^T dt\;  f_{n-1}(t) \int_T^s dr\; f(r-t)$. Because mathematically, as this formula shows, its result is a function of $s$ and $r$. But allowing for the physical meaning, it should be a function of $x$. Could you give me a hand on this?

Comment: $x$?  What $x$?  It's a function of $s$ and $T$

Comment: sorry, by $x$ I mean $s$. If it is a function of $s$ and $T$, it should be $P(S_K \le s) = \int_T^s  f(r) + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_0^T   f_{n-1}(t) \int_T^s  f(r-t)  dr\,dt$. $dr$ should be placed at the end of the formula.

Comment: I prefer to write multiple integrals "physics style" with the $d$(variable)'s after the integral sign rather than at the end.  It helps to make the connection between variables and endpoints clearer.

Comment: I can understand your preference, but it seems these are two different formulas. It's like $\int f(x)dx g(x)$ and $\int f(x)g(x)dx$, obviously they are not equal.

Comment: Ohhh!!! Do you mean $\int_0^T dt\;  \big( f_{n-1}(t) \int_T^s dr\; f(r-t) \big)$, rather than $\big( \int_0^T dt\;  f_{n-1}(t)\big) \big( \int_T^s dr\; f(r-t) \big)$?

Comment: If you just want to say $P(S_{n-1} \le T, T < S_n \le s) = P(S_{n-1} \le T)*P(T < S_n \le s)$, then it is incorrect.